# Not able to access deployed application

Tags: java, websphere

I have a Dynamic Web Project imported in my RAD. From this project I created an Enterprise Application Project. application.xml file of this project is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_ID" version="5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
<display-name>aa-ear</display-name>
<module id="Module_1430472038102">
  <web>
    <web-uri>project-app-web.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>web-app</context-root>
  </web>
 </module>
</application>
```

In RAD I added a WAS 7 server and deployed this application. It is properly deployed with any error. Now I am trying to access this application by URL http://localhost:9090/web-app but I am getting Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}. I tried lot of things to fix this but nothing worked out. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons.

1) What is the `HTTP` port configured in `serverindex.xml`? (Default for WAS 7 and 8 is `9080`), but you are trying to access with `9090` port in your URL.

2) If it is deployed without any error, then after you deployed the application, did you check the status in '`admin console`'. is your application started fine and shows 'started' status?

3) `HTTP 404` is resource not found, it means either the port you are using is wrong (or) the Application has no resource to serve for default URI '/'.